# Open files in git repo that have been edited since a previous commit or branch

Tags: helm, git, projectile, helm-projectile

Is there a way to provide a list of files that have been edited since a previous commit or branch with helm and projectile integration?

The use case is as follows:

1. Create feature branch `feat-my-thing` off of master.
2. Modify foo.txt and bar.txt
3. Commit changes.
4. Days pass. Work on other things.
5. Revisit `feat-my-thing` branch.
6. I'd really like to select from a list of just foo.txt or bar.txt as those are the only files with changes since `master`.

For small repos, `helm-projectile-find-file` works well because I can usually remember what I was working on.  With hundreds of files, is not as helpful especially because I'm usually only concerned with 1-5 files for a feature branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete working solution with an example keybinding for spacemacs.
The master branch is hard-coded in as the default branch to compare for file
changes against.  If you want to diff against the nearest parent branch you
would need something like this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641361

```
git diff --name-only <notMainDev> $(git merge-base <notMainDev> <mainDev>)
```

Emacs Code.  This is mostly a simplification of `helm-projectile-find-files` and the resulting calls into `projectile-current-project-files` and `projectile-dir-files`

```
(defun my:helm-projectile-changed-master ()
  "Finds files changed from master in the current project."
  (interactive)
  (let ((changed-files (my:project-files-changed-from-master)))
    (if changed-files
        (helm :sources (helm-projectile-build-dwim-source changed-files)
              :buffer "*helm projectile*"
              :prompt (projectile-prepend-project-name "Find file: "))
      (message "No files have changed from master."))))

(defun my:project-files-changed-from-master ()
  "Returns a list of files changed from master in the current project."
  (cl-mapcan
  #'my:get-files-changed-from-master-in-dir
  (projectile-get-project-directories)))

(defun my:get-files-changed-from-master-in-dir (directory)
  "Returns list of files changed from master branch in DIRECTORY."
  (let* ((root (projectile-project-root))
        (default-directory directory)
        (command "git diff --name-only master")
        (changed-files (split-string
                        (projectile-shell-command-to-string command)
                        "\n"))
        (changed-files-no-empty (delete "" changed-files))
        (get-relative-project-file-name
          (lambda (file)
            (file-relative-name (expand-file-name file directory)
                                root))))
    (projectile-adjust-files
    (mapcar get-relative-project-file-name
            changed-files-no-empty))))

(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "pj" #'my:helm-projectile-changed-master)
```